# On duplicate key insert in phonegap

Tags: sql, sqlite, cordova

Is there something for inserting into SQLite as the insert on duplicate key in MySQL?

In PhoneGap, I get a SQL syntax error on 'ON DUPLICATE'. I dont want to have to lookup each item before inserting.

My code:

```
$.each(jsondata, function(i, item) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Pricelist2 (id, name,desc,make,price) '+
                  'VALUES ('+jsondata[i].id+', '+
                           '"'+data[i].name+'", '+
                           '"'+jsondata[i].description+'", '+
                           '"'+jsondata[i].make+'", '+
                           '"'+jsondata[i].price+'")'+
                  ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '+
                      'desc=\''+jsondata[i].description+'\','+
                      'price=\''+jsondata[i].price+'\';');
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use only [syntax that is actually supported by SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html).

For this particular problem, `INSERT OR REPLACE` is likely what you want:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO Pricelist2(id,name,desc,make,price)'+
              'VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)',
              [jsondata[i].id,
               data[i].name,
               jsondata[i].description,
               jsondata[i].make,
               jsondata[i].price]);
```

(If the record already exists, `name` and `make` will also be replaced.)